# PANIC: could not locate a valid checkpoint record on postgres 13.2

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, alpine-linux

Unable to restart postgres 13.2-alpine image.

PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization

```
2021-05-06 03:45:04.728 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 10.2.1_pre1) 10.2.1 20201203, 64-bit
2021-05-06 03:45:04.730 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2021-05-06 03:45:04.731 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2021-05-06 03:45:04.737 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2021-05-06 03:45:04.745 UTC [20] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-05-06 03:26:11 UTC
2021-05-06 03:45:04.745 UTC [20] LOG:  invalid resource manager ID 58 at 0/1933908
2021-05-06 03:45:04.745 UTC [20] LOG:  invalid primary checkpoint record
2021-05-06 03:45:04.745 UTC [20] PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record
2021-05-06 03:45:04.977 UTC [1] LOG:  startup process (PID 20) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
2021-05-06 03:45:04.977 UTC [1] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
2021-05-06 03:45:04.979 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down

PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization

2021-05-06 03:45:12.426 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 10.2.1_pre1) 10.2.1 20201203, 64-bit
2021-05-06 03:45:12.428 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2021-05-06 03:45:12.429 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2021-05-06 03:45:12.434 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2021-05-06 03:45:12.440 UTC [20] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-05-06 03:26:11 UTC
2021-05-06 03:45:12.440 UTC [20] LOG:  invalid resource manager ID 58 at 0/1933908
2021-05-06 03:45:12.440 UTC [20] LOG:  invalid primary checkpoint record
2021-05-06 03:45:12.440 UTC [20] PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record
2021-05-06 03:45:12.679 UTC [1] LOG:  startup process (PID 20) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
2021-05-06 03:45:12.679 UTC [1] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
2021-05-06 03:45:12.681 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Comment: Restore from backup. What did you do to the database?